# Android Rect.intersect() not working/not being used right?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement basic collisions and can't seem to figure out how to make it work. So far I have a `Ball` object that has an android `Rect` bounds, and trying to test if it collides with a box.
I have this code so far:

```
public void collides(Ball ball) {

//  if(ball.getX() > getX() - ball.getSize() && ball.getX() < getX() + getWidth() && ball.getY() > getY() && ball.getY() - ball.getSize() < getY() + getHeight()) {
        //System.out.println("we got a hit");

        if(Rect.intersects(ball.getBounds(),new Rect(getX(), getY(), getX() + getWidth(), getY()-3) ) ) { //bottom
                System.out.println("bottom");
                ball.setYvel(0);
                ball.setXvel(0);
                //ball.setYvel(ball.getYvel() * -1);
            } 
        if(Rect.intersects(ball.getBounds(), new Rect(getX(), getY()+getHeight(), getX()+getWidth(), getY()+getHeight()+3)) ) { //top
                System.out.println("top");
                ball.setYvel(0);
                ball.setXvel(0);
                //ball.setYvel(ball.getYvel() * -1);
            } 

            if(Rect.intersects(ball.getBounds(), new Rect(getX(), getY(), getX()+3, getY()+getHeight()))) {     //left
                System.out.println("left");
                ball.setXvel(0);
                ball.setYvel(0);
                //ball.setXvel(ball.getXvel() * -1);
            } 
            if(Rect.intersects(ball.getBounds(), new Rect(getX()+getWidth(), getY(), getX()+getWidth()-3, getY()+getHeight()) )) { //right
                System.out.println("right");
                ball.setXvel(0);
                ball.setYvel(0);
                //ball.setXvel(ball.getXvel() * -1);
            }
}
```

I've painted out the rectangles and it covers the entire box, but doesn't seem to always respond when colliding. Also painted out the rect for the ball and it is where it should be. It sometimes works right with the left side of the box, but passes through the rest.
I also will probably get into non-perpendicular collisions, so if anyone knows how to do that, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`intersect()` sets the rectangle bounding the ball to the intersection rectangle. Thus your ball bounding rectangle is getting smaller. You should use `intersects()` instead.

Comment: I tried that, ill update the snippet, but it doesn't seem to help

Comment: Fixed it (Seven more to go)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I forgot to update the bounds in the ball class. I can't believe I spend 5 hours trying to fix this and it was just some little line of code.

Comment: This is why we use a debugger :D